# findViewByID in MaterialList produces NPE

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using the MaterialList library from Dexafree to create a list of cards. The MaterialList is essentially a Recyclerview from my understanding of how it works.

I'm trying to get an object in one of these cards. So for example,

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_doestitlematch_confirm_item_specs)).getText().toString()
```

However, this produces an NPE. I've tried other solutions such as

```
((EditText) mListView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i).getRootView().findViewById(R.id.edittext_doestitlematch_confirm_item_specs)).getText().toString()
```

And this doesn't seem to work either. Does anyone have any ideas? I have a feeling the view just doesn't exist anyone in the RecyclerView but any other way of getting it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a boat-load of methods in a sequence without ever checking if their values are actually valid.

Break it down piece by piece and null check everything that can return null until you find the root cause.

My best guess would be that you are either trying to retrieve a non-existant ID, or, the text from the component is null, and the toString() call is what is throwing the NPE, by calling getText(), which can definitely return null.

Comment: Hi, I've followed your suggestion and done some debugging on the elements I'm having trouble with. The error I get is "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.getRootView()' on a null object reference" and I can confirm the object is null even though it is in my view. Could this be the behavior of the RecyclerView that the MaterialList library is built on?

Comment: Sorry just to confirm now. I've tried just check the elements that I can see in the list and they don't return null whereas any other elements that are outside of my view of the list, return null.

Comment: Yes, "if (ref != null) //Do Operation else //Do something else"

Comment: That's fine thank you. Now my next question would be retrieving the values of these IDs that are null due to the RecyclerView